# Associations with Doctrine 2.1

Tags: associations, doctrine-orm

I'm busy with Doctrine these days. but i'm confused about associations. while i designate an entity, unfortunately i can't do associations between in two tables. one2many, many2one or whatever.

i read document about Associations Mapping in [website](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html). and i'm so confused.

I wanna do simple example. Please help me !

here we go !

I have two tables. One of them is **users** and the other one is **comments**. I know that is very simple but everything is for my benefaction.

**users** table has three columns that are **ID**, **name**, **comment_id**.

**comments** table has **id** and **comment_text** columns. (i think, problem is here)

and now that my **users.php** file

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="users") */
class User{

/** @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer") */
private $id;

/** @Column(name="name", length=55, type="string") */
private $name;

/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="author")
 */
private $commentID;

public function addComment($comment){

    $this->commentID[] = $comment;

}

public function setName($new){
    $this->name = $new;
}

public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}

public function __construct()
   {
       $this->commentID = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
   }
}
```

and **comments.php** file

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="comments") */
class Comment{
   /** @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name="author", type="integer")
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="commentID")
   */
private $author;

   /** @Column(name="comment_text", type="text") */
private $commentText;

public function setAuthor($author)
  {
      $author->addComment($this);
      $this->author = $author;
  }

public function setComment($new){
     $this->commentText = $new;
  }

public function getComment(){
      return $this->commentText;
  }
}
```

that's it. I wanna insert, select, update and delete items in two tables.

```
$person = new User();
$person->setName('Jack Sparrow');

$comment = new Comment();
$comment->setComment('Hello pirates !');
$comment->setAuthor($person);

$em->persist($person);
$em->persist($comment);
$em->flush();
```

that code works well but value of **comment_id** column always is zero = 0 in **users** table. I think i have a big wrong in somewhere.

Help where i am wrong !

regards....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the `@ManyToOne` on your `comment` entity. You are trying to link it with `comment_id` column, but that's not necessary, and in your example is wrong. It should be something like the following (**just a sample, correct code below**)

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="comments") */
class Comment{
    /** @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name="id", type="integer") */
    private $comment_id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="commentID")
     */
    private $author;
    //other declarations//
}
```

Also, I doubt that your database is designed correctly. In your current schema, you have `User`->`Comment` association, so actually `User` is on `Many` side of relation. So, for `User` to have multiple `Comment`s your db structure should be the following (pseudocode):

```
users (id, name)
comments(id, comment_text, author_id)
```

In this case, your Entitites declarations will be

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="users") */
class User{

    /** @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(name="name", length=55, type="string") */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="author")
     */
    private $comments;

    //Other declarations//
}

/** @Entity @Table(name="comments") */
class Comment{
    /** @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(name="comment_text", type="text") */
    private $text;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="comments")
     * @JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencesdColumn="id")
     */
    private $author;

    //Other declarations//
}
```

Have a look at [Associations Mapping](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) chapter of Doctrine 2.0 reference, it contains samples of common associations use-cases.

Comment: @JOHN; 10x a lot. it is very helpful.